# TypeOrm : DataTypeNotSupportedError thrown during defining one-one relationships in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, typeorm

I am trying to define a simple one-to-one relationship using TypeOrm  with JS and Babel (for class decorators)

These are the two models:

```
@Entity()
export default class Account {
    // ID Columns etc. 
    ...

    @OneToOne(type => User, user => user.account) 
    @JoinColumn()
    user;
}
```

```
@Entity()
export default class User {
    // ID Columns etc. 
    ...

    @OneToOne(type => Account account => account.user) 
    account;
}
```

This setup throws this error -

```
DataTypeNotSupportedError: Data type "" in "User.account" is not supported by "postgres" database.
    at new DataTypeNotSupportedError (/workspace/node_modules/typeorm/error/DataTypeNotSupportedError.js:7:28)
    at /workspace/node_modules/typeorm/metadata-builder/EntityMetadataValidator.js:74:27
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at EntityMetadataValidator.validate (/workspace/node_modules/typeorm/metadata-builder/EntityMetadataValidator.js:71:36)
    at /workspace/node_modules/typeorm/metadata-builder/EntityMetadataValidator.js:42:74
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at EntityMetadataValidator.validateMany (/workspace/node_modules/typeorm/metadata-builder/EntityMetadataValidator.js:42:25)
    at Connection.buildMetadatas (/workspace/node_modules/typeorm/connection/Connection.js:498:33)
    at Connection.<anonymous> (/workspace/node_modules/typeorm/connection/Connection.js:127:30)
    at step (/workspace/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:139:27)
```

I have checked the documentation and the js + babel example here at https://github.com/typeorm/babel-example

The entities in the example look identical to the ones I have defined but it still fails.

Is there any alternate way to approach one to one relationships using typeorm? Or how do I fix this?

Comment: Hey, did you solve this issue ? I have the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Entity()
export default class Account {
    // ID Columns etc. 
    ...

    @OneToOne(()=> User, (user) => user.account) 
    @JoinColumn()
    user!: User;
}

@Entity()
export default class User {
    // ID Columns etc. 
    ...

    @OneToOne(()=> Account, (account) => account.user) 
    account!: Account;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
@OneToOne(type => Account account => account.user) 
account;
```

a comma is missing. Also, I'd suggest you to give the property a type, like this:

```
@OneToOne(type => Account, account => account.user) 
account: Account;
```